# Extend image fullscreen in bootstrap carousel / prevent from extending past viewport

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel, fullscreen

I am using the latest version of bootstrap. I have a fullscreen carousel with content inside of it that is vertically centered, 2 issues:

1. I cannot extend the image all the way, I am missing a `height:100%;` somewhere in my code I am sure of it but I cant figure out where it should be!

   **EDIT:** another issue I am having is getting my `.carousel-content` class to extend fullscreen as well (so the content is vertically centered) this works if there is a fixed height on the slider but it is just aligned to the top on the fullscreen version
2. My fullscreen carousel is not taking the navbar into account so it extends past the viewport. I was able to fix this by adding `margin-top:-121px;` (the height of my nav/header) but this is not a fix i like as 121px of the image are hidden under the header.

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bwupc7g6/1/

Am sure this will be useful to other users as well if anyone can take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.carousel-inner .item div {
  height:100%;
}
```

I recommend you to use a proper class name for that div since it doesn't have one.

Comment: Ah okay awesome idk how I missed that one! Also do you have any idea on #2?

Comment: Could you describe it better. You want the navbar be infront of the carrousel?

Comment: I have updated my question with another issue I am having if you can take a glance, but for #2 the carousel does not take into account that I have a navbar above it so it extends past the size of the page, you should not be able to scroll when you get to the page but if you check the fiddle you can scroll down a little bit (by the height the space at the top is)

Comment: check this out http://jsfiddle.net/bwupc7g6/3/ on this approach i used absolute position to put the navbar in front.

Comment: I achieved this with margin-top:-121px; but then 121px of the carousel is hidden under the navbar (content is not centered) it is the same in the example you provided too

Comment: combine the absolute position of the navbar with the "margin-top: 121px" on the ".carousel-inner .item div" like this http://jsfiddle.net/bwupc7g6/5/

Comment: It looks like this worked for the carousel/content!!!! But for some reason the arrows are still going underneath the navbar so they are not centered, do you have any idea why that is?

Comment: add this ".left.carousel-control, .right.carousel-control {  top:121px; }" http://jsfiddle.net/bwupc7g6/6/

Comment: Ahh I was trying all sorts of crazy stuff thank you!! Can you maybe see what the issue is with centering the content vertically inside the slider? This template is using the same method to center it and it is working perfectly here: http://www.aliensix.com/boltdemoup/navbar-top-slider/

Comment: do you want to hire me xD. add the padding to the alginment classes you are using ex. ".center-vertically { padding-top:121px; display:table-cell; text-align:center; vertical-align:middle; }" http://jsfiddle.net/bwupc7g6/7/ I recommend you to use som css pre-processor like compass since you are repeating a lot of values.

Comment: Im sorry man I've just been killing myself last 2 days over this lol but if I do the padding then its not fully responsive :/ I assumed that the height:100% on my .carousel-content class would work because if it is a fixed height the content is vertically centered but at height:100% it is not doing anything at all, I swear last issue lol

Comment: it is responsive if your nav height is also fixed, but if in some @media directive you are changing or hiding the nav you should change the top of the arrows and the margin-top of the slider and the all the properties relative to the nav height or how are you managing the responsiveness?